# Cache image with nsurlcache

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, nsurlcache

I have an image that I'm getting ready to upload.  I know that I can download it and store it in the AFNetworking NSURLCache I already have, but I already know the what the url will be before I upload it so I want to cache it before I upload it using AFNetworking's NSURLCache.

How can I cache something in NSURLCache without it being downloaded aka an NSURL response?  Or can I create an NSURLResponse from a local download aka within the application?

I dont want to have to download it if i'm the user that uploaded it.  Also i want to utilize AFNetworking's cache (NSURLCache) before i separately create my own.

Here is how AFNetworking's NSURLCache works under the hood: [AFNetworking's NSURLCache](http://www.fantageek.com/blog/2015/06/18/understanding-afnetworking-cache/)

I'm using the latest version of AFNetworking: [image]

Comment: from where you are going to upload and to which place. from your app to the server ?

Comment: Yes I'm uploading the image from my device to my AWS S3 bucket, but I want to cache it prior so when i go to download images later, if its my image, just grab it from the cache instead of downloading it

Comment: you need to tell which afnetworking version you are using

Comment: @Shubhank Please see my updated answer per your request.  I'm using the latest version - pod v3.1.0

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/32cf30a2451917c25d853fccb9e112b64415595e/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/AFAutoPurgingImageCache.m#L110 You can see this function which actually caches the thing. you need to just pass your request url and it will cache along that string

Comment: Wow! thats so straight forward.  How can I do that with videos?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110848/discussion-between-user2792129-and-shubhank).